# How to access the gallery in phonegap/android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, image-gallery

I am new to phonegap.

I do not know what is the procedure to access the gallery of the phone using javascript?

I did not find any related article regarding this .So,Please help me!!

**EDIT VERSION**

Well,While waiting for your answers I was trying with the example in the phonegap docs...

Well, **this connects me to the GALLERY**.

While Executing that program I found out that,pics that are taken from the app,does not get stored anywhere.

**2 queries**

**query 1)** That is i take pictures,...those are there....when i come and open the app for the 2nd time..no Pics(here I open the application **twice**)

**query 2)** Suppose, I select 1 photo from the gallery,now i want the other photo too...when i select the second the 1st one vanishes....(here I open the application **once**)

**Where should I store** the photos clicked from the app and **HOW should I store** --i mean the procedure to do it/method to be followed.

suggestions and solutions please!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to write plugins for specific platforms, and call them, so you'll have to go native for that

Comment: Is there any  plugin to get an idea how to go about?

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins and check the official PhoneGap documentation on how to write plugins and call them

Comment: Using the same PhoneGap API I would store (in localStorage, a small db, etc...) the fetched imagesURIs when the images were taken
    image.src = imageURI;
Then at other app start just go fetch the imageURIs from whatever storage you chose and load the images. I believe you can also create a photoalbum and just load the images on second start, the documentation seems pretty extensive

Answer (score 2):

You may find this helpful

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/27/awesome-mobile-image-gallery-web-app/

http://www.photoswipe.com/

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pick an image from your photo gallery, check the **"Full Example"** of phonegap api : [camera.getPicture](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture)

There is a camera option which allows you to take a photo from gallery (PHOTOLIBRARY)

```
Camera.PictureSourceType = {
    PHOTOLIBRARY : 0,
    CAMERA : 1,
    SAVEDPHOTOALBUM : 2
};
```

Comment: Gaepi, that is what i was trying.WHat I noticed is ONCE you the photo you take is  not there when you open the application.what should i do to store thiese photos so that next time I open it,I can access them...say datewise

Comment: Ok. So maybe you should give us more precision (in your first post) of what you want exactly, because I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

> While Executing that program, I found out that pics that are taken from the app are not get stored anywhere.

To store in the photo gallery the photos taken by the app, use the option `saveToPhotoAlbum`:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 40, allowEdit: true, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, **saveToPhotoAlbum: true** });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi these are the option you can use with the Camera Capture. i think when you set saveToPhotoAlbum to true it will save your images to photo Album that you can access later.
but if you looking for multiple image upload at a time from gallery you can't do that.
but you can upload the multiple image from the camera capture.

```
{ 
  quality : 75,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit : true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 100,
  targetHeight: 100,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false 
};
```